# Getting type of generic from interface

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection

In method WhatGenericTypeIAm I want to get information about implemention not abstraction of the generic, so i could see "Person" not "AbstractModel"
Is there any way to do that or this is not possible and need to be redesign?

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new ContainerBuilder();
        container.RegisterType<SomeA>();
        container.RegisterType<MyDependency>().As<IMyDependency<Person>>();  // generic T is a Person
        var buildedContainer = container.Build();

        var someBase = buildedContainer.Resolve<SomeA>();
        someBase.SayName();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IMyDependency<in T>
{
    void WhatGenericTypeIAm();
}

public class MyDependency : IMyDependency<AbstractModel>
{
    private string objectName = typeof (AbstractModel).Name;

    public void WhatGenericTypeIAm()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My generic type is " + objectName );  // it shows "AbstractModel" but i want to see "Person"
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractModel  // will be implemented not only by Person
{

}

public class Person : AbstractModel
{

}

public abstract class SomeBaseClass<T>
where T : AbstractModel
{
    private readonly IMyDependency<Person> _myDependency;

    public SomeBaseClass(IMyDependency<Person> myDependency)  // generic T is Person 
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;
    }

    public void SayName()
    {
        _myDependency.WhatGenericTypeIAm();
    }
}

public class SomeA : SomeBaseClass<Person>
{
    public SomeA(IMyDependency<Person> myDependency) : base(myDependency)
    {

    }
}
```

@BrentWorden hmm i don't really get it, now i have this and it's the same problem

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new ContainerBuilder();
        container.RegisterType<SomeA>();
        container.RegisterType<SomeB>();
        container.RegisterType<MyDependency<AbstractModel>>().As<IMyDependency>();  // generic T is a Person
        var buildedContainer = container.Build();

        var someBase = buildedContainer.Resolve<SomeA>();
        someBase.SayName();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IMyDependency
{
    void WhatGenericTypeIAm();
}

public class MyDependency<T> : IMyDependency
{
    private string objectName = typeof (T).Name;

    public void WhatGenericTypeIAm()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My generic type is " + objectName );  // it shows "AbstractModel" but i want to see "Person"
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractModel  // will be implemented not only by Person
{

}

public class Person : AbstractModel
{

}

public class OtherPerson : AbstractModel
{

}

public abstract class SomeBaseClass<T>
where T : AbstractModel
{
    private readonly IMyDependency _myDependency;

    public SomeBaseClass(IMyDependency myDependency)  // generic T is Person or OtherPerson
    {
        _myDependency = myDependency;
    }

    public void SayName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My name is " + typeof(T)); // i want this in _myDependency

        _myDependency.WhatGenericTypeIAm();
    }
}

public class SomeA : SomeBaseClass<Person>
{
    public SomeA(IMyDependency myDependency) : base(myDependency) //myDependency T is Person
    {

    }
}

public class SomeB : SomeBaseClass<OtherPerson>
{
    public SomeB(IMyDependency myDependency) : base(myDependency)      //myDependency T is OtherPerson
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is there a reason `T` is not used at all in `SomeBaseClass`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla no, it can be used there

Comment: Change MyDependency<AbstractModel> to MyDependency<Person> with the Unitiy registration.

Comment: But then MyDependency is tight coupled to Person and i want Implement it with any types derrived from AbstractModel - Person and OtherPerson

Answer (score 2):

The MyDependency class must be declared as a generic class.  Then you can use the type of the generic to do what you wish:

```
public class MyDependency<T> : IMyDependency<T>
{
    private string objectName = typeof(T).Name;

    public void WhatGenericTypeIAm()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My generic type is " + objectName);
    }
}
```

The way you have it now, MyDependency is statically typed with AbstractModel.

Comment: i don't really get it, after that i have the same problem, see above

Answer (score 0):

The type `MyDependency` has no notion of `Person`, even when you're running it.

If any of the methods of `MyDependency` happen to actually use a `Person` object, then you'll be able to get the name `"Person"` from that, but until you're actually using a `Person`, object, the data that you're trying to print simply doesn't exist.

So, even if you write

```
IMyDependency<Person> dependency = new MyDependency();
```

your object is `new MyDependency()`, and `IMyDependency<Person>` is just a property of the variable that you put it in.  The actual object itself has no concept of `Person`, and It doesn't need to have one.  All It cares about is that whatever object it deals with is or derives from `AbstractModel`